# Do $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\phi}}=0$ implies $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates

If $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, then $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is unbounded. I'v tried to derive $\nabla$ in sc and there is:
$$
z=rcos(\theta)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}=\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial{\theta}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}+\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}}\\
$$
Can I use $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\phi}}}$ here?

Comment: You state correctly that if $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, then $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is unbounded. Or as I would say: the inverse function $x(y)$ does not even exist . What makes you think going go polar coordinates and partial derivatives makes things any better ?

Comment: This is how this problem started - I tried to derive gradient in spherical coordinates, but cannot because of that $\infty$

Comment: @KurtG. If this method is wrong can you point me the other way to do it?

Comment: When I do that exercise I use the chain rule on the polar-Cartesian coordinate transformation and then invert a matrix. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: @KurtG. I just want to know if $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}=0$ when $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\phi}}=0$

Comment: if this is a duplicate you can close it but do relation $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\phi}}}$ works in general?

Comment: What is the original problem that you want to solve?

Comment: $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{z}}=0$ when $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\phi}}=0$ is just as wrong as it is for $dy/dx$. You don't need that. Follow my advice. The partial derivatives you calculate are all explicit. No need to do hokus pokus with derivatives of inverse functions.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, thank you so first I need $r \theta \phi$ of $x y z$ and then just use $\phi=tan^{-1}(y/x)$

Comment: @user1046533 I wanted to derive gradient in spherical coordinates

Comment: @konto . Something like that ($\phi=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$). Easier in 2d than in 3d. BTW the inversion of the matrix I mentioned is related to the derivative of the inverse function, i.e., to $dy/dx$ vs $dx/dy$. BUT this is theoretical stuff. You will be much wiser when you have actively done it.